# Reverting .filter changes

Tags: angular

I'm using the `filter` method to filter information in my website.

```
 this.result.combos = this.result.combos.filter(....);
```

I made a `reset` button so I can revert those changes and revert everything to the original data without filters.

I make an API call to make my data, and I save the `data` retrived with 2 variables: `result` and `freshData`.

I make my `filter` on my `result` and when I call the `revert()` method I do this:

```
revert() {
       this.result = this.freshData;
   }
```

Sadly it's not working because both are binded to the `data` received which is changing - which means i'm unable to revert the `filter` changes.

How I can reset them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're modifying `this.result.combos`, which is changing `this.freshData.combos` reference as well. To avoid that, create a variable to hold a reference to original `combos` list before filtering it:

```
this.freshCombos = this.result.combos;
```

Then in your revert function:

```
revert() {
   this.result.combos = this.freshCombos;
}
```

Comment: Hm.. I don't see anything different from what I did?

Comment: The difference is `freshData.combos` will not be able to retain the old reference to the unaltered `combos` list while `freshCombos` will.

Comment: I created this plunker to demonstrate:  http://plnkr.co/edit/MkglDQ9ArNDmvpXzTECY It's working now. If you swap the comment part inside the `Component` and the `<li>`, you will see that it'll not work.